# Download the ssl certificate from website on Android device

Tags: android, macos, google-chrome, ssl-certificate

1. Server's website is only accessible from my Android device (because a VPN connection is needed to access it).
2. My MacBook cannot connect to the website because the VPN connection is only available on the
   phone.

How to download the SSL certificate from the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, I will demonstrate how to do this for **google.com**, but it will work for any website accessible on the phone

1. Connect an Android device to your computer (make sure USB debugging is on).
2. Open Google Chrome on your computer and go to `chrome://inspect` to show a list of debug-enabled WebViews on your device.
   [image]
3. Click "Inspect".
   [image]
4. Select "Security" and click on "View Certificate" as shown in the picture.
5. Now, drag the certificate icon (you could also drag a root CA certificate or an intermediate one) to your Desktop.
   [image]
6. Done.